# node.js: expensive request

Tags: javascript, node.js, optimization

*Hi, everyone!* I need some help in my first app:

I’m creating an application with express+node.js as the background. There is no database. I’m using 3rd-party solution with some functions, that doing calculations, instead.

## Front

50 objects. Every object has one unique value: random number. At start I have all these objects, I need to calculate some values for every object and position it on the form based on the calculated results.

Each object sends: `axios.get('/calculations?value=uniqueValue')` and I accumulate the results in an array. When `array.length` will be equal 50 I will compare array elements to each other and define (x, y) coordinates of each object. After that, objects will appear on the form.

## Back

```
let value = uniqueValue; // an unique value received from an object
let requests = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 1500; i++) { // this loop is necessary due to application idea
      requests.push(calculateData(value)); // 3rd-party function
      value += 1250;
    }
let result = await Promise.all(requests);
let newData = transform(result); // here I transform the calculated result and then return it.
return newData
```

Calculations for one object cost 700 ms. All calculations for all 50 objects cost ≈10 seconds. 3rd-party function receives only one value at the same time, but works very quickly. But the loop `for (let i = 1; i < 1500; i++) {…}` is very expensive.

## Issues

1. 10 seconds is not a good result, user can’t wait so long. May be I should change in approach for calculations?
2. Server is very busy while calculating, and other requests (e.g. `axios.get('/getSomething?params=something')` are pending.

Any advice will be much appreciated!

Comment: It would help to see your `calculateData()` function. How much time does it take to return its Promise, vs. how much time does it take to resolve it?

Comment: ```async function calculateData (value) {
try {
   let a = await thirdParty.One(value);
   let b = await thirdParty.Two(a);
   return { value: b }      
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      value: undefined,
      error: error.message,
    };
  }```

Comment: ```const { performance } = require('perf_hooks');
  let timing = [];
  let sum = 0;  
  for (let i = 0; i < 1500; i++) {
      let start = performance.now();        
      requests.push(calculateData(value));
      let time = performance.now() - start;
      
     sum += time;
     timing.push(time);      
    }
    console.log('min', Math.min(...timing))
    console.log('max', Math.max(...timing))
    console.log('avg', sum / 1500)```

min 0.2523209974169731
max 1.7772289998829365
avg 0.30228084793779997

Comment: ```let start = performance.now(); 
let result = await Promise.all(requests);
let time = performance.now() - start;
console.log('time', time)```

time 117.94126300141215
time 106.5162639990449
time 100.94390600174665
time 101.12798599898815
time 109.25484200194478
time 98.82581099867821
time 111.18619300052524

Answer (score 0):

```
You can make the call in chunks of data using async.eachLimit


var values = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 1500; i++) { // this loop is necessary due to application idea
      values.push(value);
      value += 1250;
    }
     var arrayOfItemArrays = _.chunk(values, 50);

      async.eachLimit(arrayOfItemArrays, 5, eachUpdate, function(err, result){let 
      newData = transform(result); 
      return newData ;
});

function eachUpdate(req_arr, cb){
  var result = []
  req_arr.forEach(fucntion(item){
     calculateData(item).then((x){
     result.push(x);
  });
 cb(result);
}
```